# Save simulation data to binary in C

Tags: c, gsl

(EDITED)
I have a particle simulator in C where I generate files with the particle states per integration step containing time, position, and velocity components. The code works well, but the resulting text files can easily go to gigabytes of data, with billions of lines. My initial idea is trying to save those files in binary instead in order to save space. I'm also using GSL for the ODEs.
If so, I'm trying to save to binary file with `fwrite`. The following is a minimal working example:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_odeiv2.h>

int uniformFieldODE(double t, const double s[], double f[], void *params);

int main() {

    int noPrimaries = 1;

    double q = 1.0;
    double m = 1.0;

    double B[3] = { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };            
    double E[3] = { 0.1, 0.0, 0.1 };

    double x0[3];  // = {0, 0, 0};                 // Initial position
    double v0[3];  // = {1, 1, 1};                 // Initial velocity

    double t0 = 0.0;
    double tf = 5000.0;
    double dt = 0.05;

    double h = 1.0e-06;
    double epsAbs = 1.0e-08;
    double epsRel = 1.0e-10;

    char *file = "lorentz";

    const gsl_rng_type *T = gsl_rng_ranlxs0;
    gsl_rng *r = gsl_rng_alloc(T);
    gsl_rng_set(r, (unsigned long)time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < noPrimaries; i++) {

        x0[0] = gsl_rng_uniform(r);
        x0[1] = gsl_rng_uniform(r);
        x0[2] = gsl_rng_uniform(r);
        v0[0] = gsl_rng_uniform(r);
        v0[1] = gsl_rng_uniform(r);
        v0[2] = gsl_rng_uniform(r);

        char fileNumber[i+1];
        char fileName[i+20];
        char extension[8] = ".bin";
        sprintf(fileNumber, "%d", i+1);
        strcpy(fileName, file);
        strcat(fileName, fileNumber);
        strcat(fileName, extension);  
    
        // Initial conditions & parameters
        const int dimension = 6;          // number of differential equations
        double s[dimension];              // Initial state vector
        int status;                       // status of driver function
        double paramsB[8];
        paramsB[0] = q;
        paramsB[1] = m;
        paramsB[2] = B[0];
        paramsB[3] = B[1];
        paramsB[4] = B[2];
        paramsB[5] = E[0];
        paramsB[6] = E[1];
        paramsB[7] = E[2];

        s[0] = x0[0]; s[1] = x0[1]; s[2] = x0[2];
        s[3] = v0[0]; s[4] = v0[1]; s[5] = v0[2];

        // File creation for state storing
        FILE *data = fopen(fileName, "wb");
    
        // Integrator configuration
        double t, t_next;
        gsl_odeiv2_system odeSystem;
        odeSystem.function = uniformFieldODE;
        odeSystem.dimension = dimension;
        odeSystem.params = paramsB;

        t = t0;
        gsl_odeiv2_driver *drv;
        drv = gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new(&odeSystem, gsl_odeiv2_step_rk8pd, h, epsAbs, epsRel);

        for (t_next = t0 + dt; t_next <= tf; t_next += dt) {
        
            status = gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply(drv, &t, t_next, s);
            if (status != GSL_SUCCESS) {
                printf("Error: status = %d\n", status);
                break;
            }
            //fprintf(data, "%.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e\n", t, s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5]);
            char str[100];
            sprintf(str, "%.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e\n", t, s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5]);
            fwrite(&str, sizeof(str), 1, data);
        }
        gsl_odeiv2_driver_free(drv);
        fclose(data);
    }

    return 0;
}

int uniformFieldODE(double t, const double s[], double f[], void *params){

    (void)(t); /* avoid unused parameter warning */
    double *lparams = (double *)params;

    double q  = lparams[0];
    double m  = lparams[1];
    double mu = q / m;

    double Bx = lparams[2];
    double By = lparams[3];
    double Bz = lparams[4];

    double Ex = lparams[5];
    double Ey = lparams[6];
    double Ez = lparams[7];

    f[0] = s[3];
    f[1] = s[4];
    f[2] = s[5];
    f[3] = mu * (Bz*s[4] - By*s[5] + Ex);
    f[4] = mu * (Bx*s[5] - Bz*s[3] + Ey);
    f[5] = mu * (By*s[3] - Bx*s[4] + Ez);
    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem is that the output still comes out as text, even if it has **.bin** as extension. Some unreadable characters show up in the beginning of the strings, but otherwise the output is the same as of a text file:

```
1.00000e-04 7.14907e+08 7.14919e+08 2.14475e+08 -1.30229e+08 -9.46995e+06 -9.50139e+06
5せ2.00000e-04 7.14894e+08 7.14918e+08 2.14474e+08 -1.30245e+08 -9.31686e+06 -9.43359e+06
```

I'm sure that there's a simple way of doing this, but I cannot figure it out. I'll really appreciate any inputs.

From my original post I got feedbacks that binary might not be the way to go to preserve all the data. So my goal here is to find an output format with a small size when compared to pure text files.

The files will later be used for data analysis via e.g. Python with numpy and/or pandas.

Comment: File extensions are just a hint. C won’t care; if you print text to a file you get text in the file. And what format did you expect to get? There’s no one ‘binary format’; you’ll have to decide on, and write the code for, some _specific_ binary format.

Comment: Please create a [mre]. [Edit] your question and explain what you want to do with the data in the file. You could write binary data by writing the variables directly instead of using `sprintf`, but the binary representation is implementation dependent, so reading the data on other systems or with programs built using a different compiler might fail. I don't see a definition of array `s`. Assuming `double` type, writing binary data will probably use 8 bytes per number. Your text format has 12 characters/bytes, so your would not gain much. You could compress the output file, e.g. using `gzip`.

Comment: Hmm, some binary formats could save some space but do not expect too much. A 64 bits integer, or a double will use 8 bytes in memory, meaning 8 characters, while your text format uses 13. So you can expect a 38% saving, if you can avoid any loss.

Comment: @Bodo, thanks a lot for the help. You can clearly see a limitation on my knowledge. I fully understand your explanation, and now it is clearer that maybe binary file is not the way forward.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, thanks for the help. With yours and others inputs, it is now more clear how the binary file will/won't work.

Comment: You only got comments, not an answer because you didn't give enough information. You should explain in your question what you want to do with the resulting file. Then someone may suggest a solution.

Comment: @Bodo, things got more clear to me on the way forward, and maybe I don't need a formal answer here. Should I delete this post? Or?

Comment: The purpose of this site is not only to answer questions for you personally but also to provide answers for people that may have a similar question. It might help others if you would provide more details.

Comment: @Bodo, thanks. I've updated the post with a working example, and trying to explain better what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: " My initial idea is trying to save those files in binary instead in order to save space." --> pipe the file output through your favorite data compressor to save space.

Comment: Rather than `%.5e`, consider `%a` as it saves more relevant info as text without incurring much space.

Comment: Your question still does not tell what you want to do with the output file. Do you want to have human-readable data? Do you want to read the data for further processing in the same or a different program? Something else?

Comment: @Bodo, I edited once again and mentioned that I'll later on need to read those files with Python for data analysis and modelling :) Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: Please also add your OS. Although it is possible to read binary data with Python, I would not recommend doing this way. [Brad Lanam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1930666/brad-lanam)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77431623/10622916) mentions using `libz` to compress the output. Unfortunately it does not show an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Brad Lanam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1930666/brad-lanam)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77431623/10622916) mentions using `libz` to compress the output. Unfortunately it does not show an example.

If your program would write text output to `stdout`, not to a file, like

```
printf(str, "%.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e\n", t, s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5]);
```

you could use a pipe like

```
yourprogram | gzip > output.txt.gz
```

In Python you can probably use classes `gzip` or `libz` to process a compressed input stream or you can use `gzip` in a pipe again like

```
gzip -dc output.txt.gz | python_program
```

Comment: Dear @Bodo, thanks for the help again. By using gzip, my output file becomes ~4x smaller than the original text file. That helps me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Edit:  Consider using libz to write out a compressed data file.

A very non-portable method is to simply write the entire data structure out to disk.  Note that pointers to other data items would need to be written out separately.

Advantages:

- Very fast to write and read.
- Saved double precision would be better than text.

Disadvantages:

- Extremely non-portable.  The data may not be transferable to other
  machines.  With doubles in the structure, I wouldn't even try.  Using only the integer types defined in <inttypes.h>, and using the same compiler on all machines, with care, I could probably make a semi-portable binary data file.
- The data cannot be examined manually.
- All compiler generated padding within the structure will remain.  And as Serge pointed out, there may not be a lot of space saved.

This method is best for data that needs to be temporarily saved on the same machine.

Binary data files used to be much more common when computers were much smaller.  They did indeed save a lot of space.  But developers and users often want to work with the data, and proprietary and un-documented binary data files are not useful.

Saving character strings in binary data files was either fixed length (limitations and space wasted), or variable length (hard to re-write, makes updating the binary data much more difficult).   You could also use a fixed length block with variable length strings within it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  double    vala;
  double    valb;
} data_t;

int
main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
  data_t    d;
  data_t    dt;
  FILE      *fh;
  int       rc;

  d.vala = 14.6;
  d.valb = 15.6;

  fh = fopen ("out.dat", "wb+");
  if (fh == NULL) {
    fprintf (stderr, "fail: unable to open file\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if (fwrite (&d, sizeof (data_t), 1, fh) != 1) {
    fprintf (stderr, "fail: unable to write\n");
    return 1;
  }
  fseek (fh, 0, SEEK_SET);
  if (fread (&dt, sizeof (data_t), 1, fh) != 1) {
    fprintf (stderr, "fail: unable to read\n");
    return 1;
  }
  fclose (fh);

  rc = memcmp (&d, &dt, sizeof (data_t));
  fprintf (stderr, "comparison: rc: %d\n", rc);

  return rc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data are still in text form because you convert them with `sprintf`. File extensions are only hints for the user and/or operating system to determine how to handle them, they do not determine the file contents.

Consider writing the binary data instead:

```
        for (t_next = t0 + dt; t_next <= tf; t_next += dt) {
            status = gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply(drv, &t, t_next, s);
            if (status != GSL_SUCCESS) {
                printf("Error: status = %d\n", status);
                break;
            }
            fwrite(&t, sizeof t, 1, data);
            fwrite(s, sizeof s[0], 6, data);
        }
```

Note however that you will need to use the same approach when reading the data back from the binary file and the machine on which you read the data must use the same representation and endianness as the one that wrote it.  Representation of `double` values is almost certainly IEEE-754 on all your systems, but endianness may differ.